# When and how var keyword of javascript pre-allocate stack memory?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, var, let

When talking about the difference between var and let keywords, one is that(memory allocation):

[The var keyword will directly pre-allocate memory space in the stack memory. Then wait until the actual assignment time to store the corresponding variable.](https://www.programmersought.com/article/14266210609/)

[The let keyword not only does not pre-allocate memory space in the stack memory area, but also checks when the stack memory allocates variables.](https://www.programmersought.com/article/14266210609/)

Could anyone give more details about it ? It really confused me and I get little information from the internet. Your prompt reply will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks pretty clear to me. var variables are allocated when the script is parsed and let are allocated when they're executed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you found those articles, but I always knew that variables declared with let *are* in fact allocated at compilation time, they're just not initialized.
All Javascript variables are subject to *hoisting*, meaning that the compiler will run through your program and specifically look for all the variables he can find, before returning to the top and start executing. The difference between var and let is that while "var" variables are initialized with *undefined*, "let" variables are not.

```
console.log(a); //undefined
console.log(b); //Error: Cannot access 'b' before initialization

var a = 5;
let b = 7;
```

This also explains why you can declare the same variable two times using "var", but not with "let". If you write:

```
var a = 5;
var a = 7;
```

The compiler will simply assign *undefined* to "a" when he finds the first declaration, and then overwrite it with *undefined* when he finds the second. The same (more or less) happens with the "function" declaration. Instead, if you do this:

```
let a = 5;
let a = 7;
```

The compiler sees that as two separate variables, counter to before, and it will result in an error:

```
//SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
```

More informations about hoisting can be found [here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-hoisting-works-with-let-and-const-in-javascript-725616df7085)